# C destroying what I have behind when adding to list

Tags: c, list

I'm writing a program that needs to execute a list of commands so i'm using this struct to save them

```
typedef struct clist {
struct clist *prox;
char comando[];
} *CommandList;
```

And this function to add to make the last node point to a new node

```
void addToList (CommandList list, CommandList x){
CommandList temp = list;

while (temp->prox != NULL)
    temp = temp->prox;

temp->prox = x;
}
```

However when I call the adding function I seem to lose everything that I had behind and I seriously can't understand why this is happening, this is the piece of code where that

```
aux = (CommandList) malloc(sizeof(struct clist));
strcpy(aux->comando,cropString(string));
aux->prox = NULL;
addToList(list,aux);
free(aux);
print_list(list);
```

When I call the print_list function the only node that is printed is the one I just added, and later on in the code I get a segfault, can someone help please?

Comment: track list variable

Comment: something like CommandList head = list; before starting to add stuff?

Comment: I mean problem might  be somewhere else. And I think it may be list (in main), I don't know...

Answer (score 3):

This happens because you are misusing flexible `struct` member: when you define an array member like this

```
char comando[];
```

it means that you will allocate space for it manually; C compiler cannot do it for you.

You fix it by allocating additional space in `malloc` for the string that you save in `comando`, like this:

```
const char* cropped = cropString(string);
aux = malloc(sizeof(struct clist)+strlen(cropped)+1);
strcpy(aux->comando, cropped);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are allocating "aux", adding it to your list, and then freeing aux.  So you now have a list that points to a deallocated chunk of memory.  When you allocate memory, you have to not deallocate it until you are done using it.